# how can i stream .m3u8 video file in Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

**Below is the code to How I initialize the Exoplayer.**

```
 private void initializePlayer(String path) {
   player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mContext, trackSelector);
   player.addListener(componentListener);
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
   MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
   player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
   playerView.setPlayer(player);
 }
```

Comment: post your buildMediaSource code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exoplayer adaptive hls streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228653/exoplayer-adaptive-hls-streaming)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the player and pass the url to it to play the any type of video in exoplayer:

```
  public void initPlayer() {
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new
            DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
    VideoSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
    ExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
}
```

and build media source function is:

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, null, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, true);
    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(VideoPlayer.this, null, httpDataSourceFactory);
    TextUtils.isEmpty(null);
    int type = Util.inferContentType(uri);
    switch (type) {
        case C.TYPE_SS:
            return new SsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_DASH:
            return new DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_HLS:
            return new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_OTHER:
            return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        default: {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported type: " + type);
        }
    }
}
```

Also call the initPlayer() in your activity oncreate function

Comment: send me link for testing

Comment: exoplayer plays the .m3u8 files like this:https://videos-3.earthcam.com/fecnetwork/5288.flv/playlist.m3u8

Comment: can you share the solution with me .

Comment: Please, share the solution.